# EXCEL VBA code to handle RightsWatch software

Tags: excel, vba

I have Macro whcich was working fine till now, however My organization installed a new software "RightsWatch", Which is not allowing me to save word or excel file.I am using below EXCEL VBA code to save Excel file.

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="\\10.32.124.51\Reports_New\PRESTIGE LEVEL\Automation\Pending IMs\IMs Assigned back to SOC team.xlsx"
```

Pls advise that what changes I need to handle RightsWatch software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create digital certificate for you excel that should fix the issue. You can follow the below steps to create a digital certificate on your own.

1. Go to Microsoft Office folder (eg: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15 or Office16 etc)
2. run SELFCERT.exe program
3. Give any name for your certificate and get it created.
4. Open your Excel with macro.
5. Press Alt+F11. Then Click on the menu option Tools -> Digital Signature
6. Choose Digital Certificate that you created with step 3 and click ok.
7. Save your Excl and open it again.
8. If you have any security warning : Just click on enable Content.
9. Run your macro now.
10. it should work.

Comment: Hi Carpark, thank you so much for your suggestion, I followed your instruction however it not works. same issue persists there. Pls suggest further if possible.Thanks

Comment: Probably RightsWatch may have removed your access to the folder \\10.32.124.51\Reports_New\PRESTIGE LEVEL\Automation\Pending IMs\. Can you change the folder name to some other folder, where you have write access and try it?

Comment: Still not working...same result..Thnx for your n effort

Answer (score 0):

If you're saving the file containing Macro it should be enough that you properly classify the file first (so manually save the file). All copies will then be properly classified.

However if you're creating a new file from VBA and then trying to save, it simply doesn't work. One way is to open a pre-classified template rather than creating a completely new file and then SavingAs this file.